# What is Nautilus File system type

Tags: nautilus, files, system

I am a beginner for Linux/Unix,according to what i have learn and researched there are ext ,2,3,4 and a GUI version Nautilus or such similar ones.. How do i know if graphical file managers use ext 2,3 or 4?
 i am a newbie so please be detailed as possible

Comment: Nautilus is just a file explorer... and ext2/3/4 are file systems (like FAT or NTFs)!

Answer (score 2):

EXT is the filesystem Linux uses. Similar to what FAT was and NTFS is for Windows. Instead of using a new name Linux used a number for the newer versions of this filesystem. So EXT2, EXT3 are older, and nowadays obsolete, versions of EXT4. There are also systems that use BTFRS. That one is suppose to be the next filesystem for Linux (it supports some nifty features like on the fly snapshots).

> How do i know if graphical file managers use ext 2,3 or 4?

You typically do not need to know this except when installing (just like with Windows Linux needs to have a formatted filesystem, ext4 being the current default, for it to work). ext4 uses journaling and allows for permissions. And some other features Linux needs.

If you need to know the formatting of your system there are several ways.
From command line:

```
sudo file -sL /dev/sd* | grep ext

/dev/sda2: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data
/dev/sda5: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data   
/dev/sdb1: Linux rev 1.0 ext4 filesystem data
```

But you can also use [gParted](http://gparted.org/). It is in the repositories. An example:

[image]